# libgdx: main menu doesn't show game class libgdx

Tags: android, menu, libgdx, screen, render

I am a newbie in libgdx and I have a little problem with screens and main menu.
I have a mainmenu class and it work with click on actors. The code for click is:

```
    pulsanteplay.addListener(
            new InputListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x,  `float y, int pointer, int button) {
                    System.out.println("click play");

                    game.setScreen(new GameClass());

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

and it works. If I call `Gdx.app.exit();` it works. If I call the next class, works

```
public class SplashScreen implements Screen {
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture ttrSplash;
private Timer timer;
private MainMenu mainMenuScreen;




public SplashScreen() {
    super();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    ttrSplash = new Texture("quadrato.png");

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(ttrSplash, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),    Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void hide() { }

@Override
public void pause() { }

@Override
public void resume() { }

@Override
public void show() { }

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) { }

@Override
public void dispose() {
    ttrSplash.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}
```

When I call a class that extends game and have a render method don't work. The screen don't change but the events of the game class are really generated. 
Someone could explain me why this? How do I fix this bad behavior?
Thanks for your attention

Comment: You should have only one class that extends game!

Answer (score 0):

Have that class that extends `Game` just implement `Screen` and put your code in it's corresponding methods. A screen offers everything a `Game` does so you should have no trouble converting. your `onCreate` code can be put in the `show` method or the constructor of your new `Screen` class. Now just call `setScreen()` to show this screen.

Comment: sorry but don't work. this is my class declaration: public class GameClass extends Game implements ApplicationListener, InputProcessor, com.badlogic.gdx.Screen all the actors creations are in the constructor I call  setScreen(new GameClass()); from my mainmenu class but the mainmenuscreenis always visible and the game class is invisible....

Comment: @user5618600 It's not a point of working or not. If you want to change `Screen` you should use a screen. Otherwise implement your own screen management system.

Comment: `.setScreen` needs a class that implements `Screen`. What I'm saying is to just do that. It has the same methods as `Game` but more and instead of `onCreate` you have `show` or the constructor. Doing this allows you to change to whatever screen you want. My first line in program entry usually is `.setScreen(new SomeScreen());` from there on I only work with screens.

Comment: public class SplashScreen implements com.badlogic.gdx.Screen {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    public SplashScreen() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        System.out.println("costruttore splash screen");
    }
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch.end();
    }
tryed this. don't work :(